# iOS app launch time measurement

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xamarin

How can I count the time it takes from the moment the user presses the launch button on the home screen until the moment the app is active (for example, until the viewDidAppear method of the first view controller)?

Id does not need to be programmatically but must be reliable.

Analogously in Android, logcat can be used for this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple implementation is to start a `StopWatch` in the applications main and then grab the time result in the `ViewDidAppear` method:

```
public class Application
{
    public static Stopwatch StartUpTimer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            StartUpTimer = new Stopwatch();
            StartUpTimer.Start();
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
}

public class MyUIViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {

        Console.WriteLine (Application.StartUpTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString () + "ms to startup");
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C.

Comment: App launch consists of two phases 1) pre-main and 2) post-main invokation. What question author asks is a way to measure pre-main + post-main launch time. Measuring a time elapsed from didLaunch method invokation to the first viewDidAppear is basically a post-main mesaurement

Answer (score 12):

You can go to edit scheme on Xcode and add a environment variable (DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS = 1) as shown in the image [image]

When you run the app the details will be printed on debugger output as below:

```
Total pre-main time: 481.88 milliseconds (100.0%)
         dylib loading time:  71.70 milliseconds (14.8%)
        rebase/binding time:  53.66 milliseconds (11.1%)
            ObjC setup time:  40.04 milliseconds (8.3%)
           initializer time: 316.33 milliseconds (65.6%)
           slowest intializers :
             libSystem.B.dylib :  16.71 milliseconds (3.4%)
```

Please watch the [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

We used DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS to measure our app’s pre-main() launch times

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a possibility to get process start time with C api:

```objectivec
#import <sys/sysctl.h>

static CFTimeInterval processStartTime() {
    size_t len = 4;
    int mib[len];
    struct kinfo_proc kp;

    sysctlnametomib("kern.proc.pid", mib, &len);
    mib[3] = getpid();
    len = sizeof(kp);
    sysctl(mib, 4, &kp, &len, NULL, 0);

    struct timeval startTime = kp.kp_proc.p_un.__p_starttime;
    return startTime.tv_sec + startTime.tv_usec / 1e6;
}
```

In swift you will have something like this:

```swift
private static func processStartTime() -> TimeInterval {
    var kinfo = kinfo_proc()
    var size = MemoryLayout<kinfo_proc>.stride
    var mib: [Int32] = [CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, getpid()]
    sysctl(&mib, u_int(mib.count), &kinfo, &size, nil, 0)
    let startTime = kinfo.kp_proc.p_starttime
    return TimeInterval(startTime.tv_sec) + TimeInterval(startTime.tv_usec) / 1e6
}
```

After that you can calculate startup time with the different ways.

For example I do:

```swift
let currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() + kCFAbsoluteTimeIntervalSince1970
let startupTime = currentTime - processStartTime()
```

Full post about that I found [here](https://medium.com/@michael.eisel/measuring-your-ios-apps-pre-main-time-in-the-wild-98197f3d95b4)

Comment: Is this returning milliseconds?

Comment: no, `CFTimeInterval` is in seconds, same as `NSTimeInterval`

Comment: For a swift application, where do you call those 2 lines? In the AppDelegate, right?  Anywhere particular in the AppDelegate?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to measure. If you want to measure how much time does it take for app to start (before any UI is shown): you measure it in `application:didFinishLaunching:`. If you want to measure [the same as Apple measures it](https://pilot34.medium.com/how-xcode-measures-app-launch-time-b5a66bd07c8c): you can do it in the first call of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of your first visible view controller. Also putting it into `viewDidAppear` of the first view controller will work.

Comment: Thanks for that! If you do it in `application:didFinishLaunching:`, do you get the "pre-main time"? Is apple getting the "post-main time" + "pre-main time"?

Comment: Also, is there a way to differentiate cold start vs warm start? Any good code samples out there? Thanks for all the help in advance :)

Comment: To get real pre-main time you should put this logic before `main()` is executed (in your `main.m` or `main.swift` file. 

Apple measures pre-main + main time, that's correct.

On iOS I think it is mostly impossible to differ warm and cold start. Cold start is after you rebooted the device and started your app. Warm start is when you force killed you app and started it again. System can cache some dylibs so warm start will be a bit faster, but I don't think it is worth to measure those separately.

Comment: So if I execute the code in `main.swift` and then also execute it in `application:didFinishLaunching:`, I can add those 2 values to get a version of "Launch Time"? When getting the value in `application:didFinishLaunching:`, should the pre-main time calculated in `main.swift` be subtracted?

Comment: You have `processStartTime()` function to get time when app was launched by the user, you have `currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() + kCFAbsoluteTimeIntervalSince1970` to get current time at any time. If you subtract `processStartTime` from `currentTime` you get time interval between current moment and app launch time. You can calculate this interval whenever you want. In my case I calculate **pre-main time** (in `main`) - time between app launched and main function called,  and **startup time** in the first view controller - time between app launched and first view controller rendered

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Start a timer in `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.....

Stop the timer in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, or `viewDidAppear` of the VC you are trying to profile, and NSLog it.

Comment: This does not start tracking time from when the user taps the app icon.

Comment: This is the only way. @rmaddy

Comment: Starting the timer at the start of `main` is much better than starting in `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions...`. But even that doesn't really do what the OP asks (which really can't be done).

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't get the exact time when the user touches the app's icon on homescreen, I suggest to start your app from another app, so you can get the exact time your app starts.

- Register a custom URL scheme in your app
- create a helper-app that can launch your app by a url
- log the time when the helper app launches your app (or send the timestamp to your app)
- in your app log the time when launch is done at a appropriate place (AppDelegate or the main ViewController)
- if you have sent the timestamp of the launch from the helper app, you can calculate the difference programmatically, otherwise just compare both times in the console