# React Native - Improve cold start time

Tags: ios, react-native

The project I was working is to use react native to create an iOS app.

Following is the cold start time in iPhone 5S release build

```
Pre-main time: 0.52 seconds

App did launch to javascript did load time: 2.12 seconds

JS render time: 0.74 seconds

Total time: 3.34 seconds
```

The slowest part is to wait react library to load the js bundle (2.2MB). Is the loading time looks normal? How can I improve the js bundle loading time? Thanks so much.

Reducing the js bundle size can improve the time from Application did launch to javascript did load. For a new Hello World project, it only took 0.18-0.19 seconds (iPhone 5S).

Comment: how did you measure those times? I'm facing a similar issue and I want to see exactly what part of the start up process is the slowest

Comment: Hi @CarlosJ, if I remember correctly, I logged the time before and after when the program (AppDelegate) loads the js bundle. 

And you can log the pre-main time by following this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46830981/632038

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the problem that you described really exist. As a possible solution you can use `ram-bundle` format, that `metro` bundler provides.

In this case you will not load the entire js-bundle - you will load only part, that you need at a startup (in a lot of application are a lot of places, which user may not even see, and this feature allow you load such parts, only when they are required). So you can simplify your entry point and load only small piece of your bundle.

You can look at [react-native-bundle-splitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bundle-splitter). This library well integrated with almost all popular navigation libraries and allows you to postpone a loading of specific routes. For example, if you have a login screen, you can load at start up only this screen, and all others load in background or start the loading of them, only when user can see them. And the startup time of your complex application will be almost equally as for "Hello world" application.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the time ok is up to you and your app users only =)

Obviously, if reducing the js bundle size improves the time, you should do your best to get it done. There is several steps I guess can help you:

- first of all, DRY: doubling code do increase the size
- check for using npm packages, remove unused (also as unused inner modules)
- obfuscate and minify the bundle with third-party tools

Also it should be done to reduce initializing complexity

- check an asymptotic complexity of your algorithms - is can cause to time increasing
- remove unused variables, functions and data - it can be a reason of redundant memory usage

And I can just advice you also try to affect not only an actual time but also a time feeling. For example, use an animated splash screen